# Needing help trying to solve: 'state' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a navbar to one of my projects but I keep getting a failed to compile error.

"Line 7:5:  'state' is not defined        no-undef
Line 9:5:  'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from "./Button"
import { MenuItems } from "./MenuItems"
import "../style/Navbar.css"

class Navbar extends Component{
    state = { clicked: false }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <nav className="NavbarItems">
                <h1 className="navbar-logo">MoviePlex<i className="fas fa-camera-movie"></i></h1>
                <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
                </div>
                <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                                {item.title}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
                <Button>Sign Up</Button>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: What linter are you using? ESLint? ESHint? Something else? It looks like probably ESLint ([`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef#disallow-undeclared-variables-no-undef)) but others may use the same rule names...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is relying on [public fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which are still at the proposal stage (though not for much longer). Apparently your linter either doesn't support them yet or you need to enable a rule for them.

If you can't find an option to enable it (I'm not seeing anything in the [ESLint configuration documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options), if that's what you're using), you can create your field in the constructor instead by changing this:

```
class Navbar extends Component{
    state = { clicked: false }
    // ...
```

to:

```
class Navbar extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { clicked: false };
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me solve that issue! My next question is how can i fix the handleClick? I'm fairly new to this if you have any insight I would greatly appreciate it!